# What is the kabbalistic understanding of the name אזבוג״ה?

Tags: number, mysticism-kabbalah, shemos-sacred-names, beshalach

In the sefer Brit Menucha it mentions the name of God אזבוג״ה which comes from [Shemos 15:1](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9876#v=1). I would like to understand what the kabbalistic associations with this name are. Particularly what is the reason that the name is made up of matching letters adding up to 8?

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=4759&st=&pgnum=7&hilite=

Comment: Are you over forty? ;-)